# how to make an application runs on background on flutter

Tags: flutter

I aim to make my application work on background if i clicked on the back button of the phone and not the application . So i use the widget  WillPopScope  to detect if the user pressed the back button or not . i mean i want that the back button has the same functionality as the button with circle.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return WillPopScope(
    onWillPop: () async {
      ///your code here...
      return false;
    },
    child:Scaffold(), 
  );
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [move_to_background](https://pub.dev/packages/move_to_background) plugin like this

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return WillPopScope(
    onWillPop: () async {
      MoveToBackground.moveTaskToBack();
      return false;
    },
  child:Scaffold(), 
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want **only** `android` application then you can use
[flutter_background](https://teams.microsoft.com/_#/calendarv2) plugin.

For more `advanced application` you can see this awesome [doc](https://medium.com/flutter/executing-dart-in-the-background-with-flutter-plugins-and-geofencing-2b3e40a1a124).